# Convert variable_set to d8 variables

Tags: 8, configuration

i have a variable_set  defined in d6 as follows :

```
variable_set('cleanupeditform_formkeys', array(
 'menu' => t('Menu settings'),
 'revision_information' => t('Revision information'),
 'attachments' => t('File attachments'),
 'comment_settings' => t('Comment settings'),
 'author' => t('Authoring information'),
 'options' => t('Publishing options'),
 ));
```

How i can convert to drupal 8 form ? I know for a single case it would be like

```
\Drupal::state()->set('cleanupeditform_formkeys','my_value');
```

Thanks .

Answer (score 1):

It's no different, you can also save an array in state:

```
\Drupal::state()->set('cleanupeditform_formkeys', ['foo' => 'bar']);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use `\Drupal::config()` instead of `\Drupal::state()`. States are used for hidden system values and are not deployed between environments, but configs store values/changes from site building process and could be synchronized between environments.

Comment: The OP didn't really leave any clues as to whether this data belongs in config or state (except for using state in the question), so I don't you think can say that config "should" be used here - you need more context to be able to say that for sure. But the point that there are different stores is a good one to raise